# Snap Store never prompts me to enter my password

Tags: 20.04, snap-store

I installed Snap Store when open the store and click on a software package then click on install it whines 'unable to install xxx:authorization was required'

However, no box ever appears to type the password into.

Comment: What do you see if you try installing via the terminal, for example `sudo snap install hello-world`

Comment: [sudo] password for reconfigure:
When I enter my password, it downloads helloword and installs it